# apache kylin- pivot feature not working

Tags: apache, hadoop, reporting, kylin

Hi i'm not able to use pivot feature in apache kylin, do i have to enable any property because the kylin documentation says that pivot feature is available in kylin web wizard itself.

Comment: Please have a look at point 5 in the below URL: http://kylin.apache.org/docs/tutorial/web.html                                                    i'm looking for the drag and drop feature.

Comment: Missing in Kylin 3.1.1. I assume they got rid of that feature completely.

Answer (score 0):

This jira should answer your question.

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KYLIN-1997

Thanks.